# Any magic bullet for scaling up css font sizes in all subelements of an element?

Tags: html, css

Basically, while implementing a 3rd party cookie consent thingy, the font sizes on everything are far too small. The good news is that all of their widgets have the same root element, the bad news is that only the "leaflet" elements contain inline css that determines the font size.

Is there any css option to scale up all the font sizes in all the contained elements of an element?

Comment: [mre] - please _show us_ a proper example, instead of giving us an ever-so-vague verbal description of what the structure it supposed to be.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe "important" would fix it in this case, depending on the ruthlessness of the third-party styling. (Tho, important-rules should not be used all that often)

```
.third-party-root-element h1 { font-size: 40px !important; }
.third-party-root-element h2 { font-size: 32px !important; }
.third-party-root-element p { font-size: 18px !important; }
```

Otherwise controlling the font-size based on your own "root-size":

```
.third-party-root-element * { font-size: 1rem !important; }
```